# Функция для сайта для распределения скидки по купону на все товары в корзине

Tags: php

Хочу написать функцию для распределения рублевой скидки по купону на все товары в корзине пропорционально стоимости товара.
На входе даю размер скидки в рублях и еще массив из цен, хочу сделать на выходе тот же массив но с учетом скидки
нашел функцию только расчета скидки в процентах $percent = (($rowx->Orgprice - $rowx->SalePrice)*100) /$rowx->Orgprice ;
А мне нужно от стоимости в рублях.
Плюс думаю как лучше массив из цен добавить. Кто с этим сталкивался ?

Comment: наверное, надо вспомнить пропорции из начальной школы, и перевести рубли в проценты?

Comment: С этим я разберусь, как в массив все записать

Comment: Приведите минимальный пример кода и место в котором у вас возникла проблема. Здесь не пишут код за кого-то

Comment: в массив -в в цикле. проходим по товарам и считаем скидку для каждого